# Why does my sequelize code to create one to one relationship not work successfully

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, mysql-workbench

I try to create one to one relationship as the follow

```
Const Cart = sequelize.define(***)
Const User = sequelize.define(***)

User.hasOne(Cart);
Cart.belongsTo(User);
```

this have to prevent Cart table from containing multiple fields with the same UserId when i call

```
User.createCart();
```

and when i call:

```
User.getCart()
.then(cart => {***});
```

it's work and return just one cart

but in mysql workbench it's more than one cart have the same UserId

is this true or i have to do anything else?

[[image: this is what show in mysql workbench]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking and from DB's point of view

```js
User.hasOne(Cart);
Cart.belongsTo(User);
```

are 1:N and N:1 relationships. You can only add unique index on `UserId` to prevent adding multiple records with the same `UserId` value but still if you call `createCart` several times you kinda tell Sequelize to actually create several records.
You need to rethink what you're trying to achieve by making two sequential `createCart` calls. What should happen? Some error on the second call? To ignore the second call? To update the existing record on the second call? What's your expectations?

Comment: Thank you, I thought hasOne and belongsTo together will return error if i added several records with the same UserId , because that is the meaning of User has one Cart, then what is the difference between hasOne and hasMany ?.  this is from sequelize site **<<To create a One-To-One relationship, the hasOne and belongsTo associations are used together;>>**

Comment: `hasOne` and `hasMany` in Sequelize differ by how Sequelize will convert linked records - either it will be represented as a linked object/null or as an array